# To see if a linear transformation T is isomorphic, what can be the inverse of T?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

When we check if a linear transformation is isomorphic or not, the graph above is the rule to follow. Let's say dim(V) = dim(W). Then, I need to check if I can write a formula for the inverse of T.

What is an example of inverse of T. How can a linear transformation have an inverse? I thought only matrix can have an inverse.

I am currently taking linear algebra in college. This makes me so confused. I just need an example of T having an inverse.

Comment: Can you comment on what your education level is currently? Are you self taught? or are you a student in high school or middle school? I think that might help people answer the question better because there are so many things that one should already be familiar with before going into isomorphisms, like functions and their inverses, which you seem to not know.

Comment: I am a college student taking linear algebra.

Comment: isomorphisms are just homomorphism(linear operator) that is invertible. If Im(T)=W, then it is surjective. It is a good exercise for you to show that (i) any linear transformation with zero kernel is injective (ii) a function that is both injective and surjective is invertible. Thus the scheme you provided in the picture follows.

Comment: oh if you have dim(W)=dim(V) then the following are equivalent: (i) Im(T)=W (ii) Ker(T) = {0}. This follows from Nullity rank.

Comment: I know, but I just need an example of linear transformation having an inverse. Because, I haven't seen an example like that before.

Comment: Any matrix is an example of a linear transformation. Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ matrix, and let $f : \mathbb{R}^{d} \to \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be defined as $f(x) = Mx$. Then this is a linear transformation. In fact in finite dimensional spaces, there always exists a unique matrix for each linear transformation. The inverse of this function, when it exists, can be defined as $f^{-1}(y) = M^{-1}y$.

Comment: Get two linear spaces V and W of same dimension n. Get their basis. Get an invertible nxn matrix A. Associate $T: V \rightarrow W$ with this matrix by letting $A=M_{V\rightarrow W}(T)$. If apply the scheme on the linear transformation, you shall get positive result. Compute $A^{-1}$. The inverse of T is just the linear transformation S with $M_{W\rightarrow V}(S)=A^{-1}$.

Comment: For example you can make a simple one by letting V be R3 and W be set of all 2 degree polynomial. Take the bases to be canonical ones and let A to be the identity matrix…then you get a really silly example…